# Laravel router with additional parameters

Tags: laravel, parameters, routes

I have controller which called by this route `website.lrv/products/{category-url}`

```
public function categoryProducts($uri, Request $request) { /** some code **/ }
```

I have a few links that are responsible for ordering products, i added them directly to blade template, like this:

`route('client.category.products', [
        'url'   =>  Route::current()->url, 
        'order' => 'article', 
        'by'    => 'desc'         ])`

`route('client.category.products', [
        'url'   =>  Route::current()->url, 
        'order' => 'article', 
        'by'    => 'asc'         ])`

And the request link with ordering is: 
`website.com/products/chargers?order=name&by=asc`

Now i want to add products filters. I have many filters, each filter can contain many values. The problem is that i don't know how to make route to get some like that:
`website.com/products/chargers?width=10,20,30&height=90,120,150` 
or something like that.

I need to get request array like that:

```
$request = [
    ....
    filters => [
        width  => ['10','20','30'],
        height => ['90','120','150'],
    ],
    ....

];`
```

If you need some additional info, i will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the array you are looking for by using `$request->query()` within the `categoryProducts` function.

**Edit:** Also worth noting you can access them from within your blade template using the Laravel helper function `request()`, so `{{ request()->query('width') }}` would return `xx` where `website.lrv/products/category?width=xx`.

**Edit 2:** Note that if your query string includes commas per your example `width=10,20,30` the query() will just return a comma separated string, so you would need to `explode(',',$request->query('width'))` in order to get the array of widths

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add them manually like this:
        route('client.category.products')."?order=name&by=asc";
Try this I hope it help.